# Is there a way to close a frameless window in electron without using remote?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm building an app in electronjs and I have a frameless window with a custom title bar. I was originally intending to add a close button, but that won't work as I expected it to because remote is no longer supported in electron v.14 and higher.

Is there any other way to close a frameless window only using my renderer file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `window.close()`?

Comment: Add a 'close' button to your custom html title bar. Add a 'click' event listener to the button. Upon 'click' send (using IPC via a `preload.js` script) a message to the main thread to close the window. If you need help implementing it let me know.